# What is the least possible value of $k$ for $(2y−2017)^2=k$ given the constraints.

Tags: elementary-number-theory

There are two distinct positive integer solutions for $y$ one of which is a factor is $100$. I found two solutions on [Find the least possible value of $k$ for $(2y-2017)^2 = k$ given the constraints.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3476162/find-the-least-possible-value-of-k-for-2y-20172-k-given-the-constraints). However I got confused on the first solution on the line

> If the second solution is the multiple of $100$, then $\sqrt k \equiv 17\pmod{200}$, and so again we must have $k\equiv89 \pmod{200}$, giving us a least solution of $289$.

Please help me out. ( btw if you are wondering why didn't I comment on that link. I am new to math stackexchange"

Answer (score 1):

"The second solution" in question is

$$y=\frac {2017-\sqrt k}2$$

Suppose for this $y$, $y$ is a multiple of $100$.

Then $2y = 2017-\sqrt k$ is a multiple of $200$.

By definition of modulo arithmetic:

$$\begin{align}
2017-\sqrt k &\equiv 0 &\pmod {200}\\
2017 &\equiv \sqrt k &\pmod {200}\\
\sqrt k &\equiv 17 &\pmod {200}\\
(\sqrt k)(\sqrt k) &\equiv (17)(17) &\pmod {200}\\
k &\equiv 289 &\pmod {200}\\
k &\equiv 89 &\pmod {200}\\
\end{align}$$

Comment: Thank you. I got that but how can we say 289 is the least solution?

Comment: The only smaller solution is $k=89$, which is not a square. $289$ is the next smallest solution to $k \equiv 89 \pmod{200}$.

Comment: Thank you for your help. I got it. :)